# Embed font in PDF rendering plugin in Grails

Tags: pdf, grails

I want to embed 'HelveticaNeueLTCom-BdCn.ttf' in a PDF document. I'm using Grails rendering 0.4.4 Plugin to generate PDF file.
I tried following,

```
@font-face {
   font-family: 'Helvetica';
   src: url('${grailsApplication.config.grails.serverURL}/fonts/HelveticaNeueLTCom-BdCn.ttf');
   -fs-pdf-font-embed: embed;
   -fs-pdf-font-encoding: Identity-H;
}
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The font embedding requires the below steps to be followed. This worked for me.
Try and tell me your feedback

1. The PdfRenderingService class present inside the plugin should be
   edited for this font simulation as below.

   ```
       protected doRender(Map args, Document document, OutputStream outputStream)           
       {
         def renderer = new ITextRenderer()

      // add the real font path from the server to be deployed to. 
      //I have it in the assets folder of my project
           def path=servletContext.getRealPath("/")+"assets/HelveticaNeueLTCom-BdCn.ttf"
       ITextFontResolver fontResolver=renderer.getFontResolver();

       //add the encoding and embedded types to the font
       fontResolver.addFont(path,BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);

       configureRenderer(renderer)
       renderer.setDocument(document, args.base)
       renderer.layout()
       renderer.createPDF(outputStream)
       outputStream.close();
   }
   ```
2. Add the below code in your template file

   ```
    @font-face {
       font-family: "Helvetica";
       src:    url("${grailsApplication.config.grails.serverURL}/assets/HelveticaNeueLTCom-BdCn.ttf") format("truetype"),
               url("${grailsApplication.config.grails.serverURL}/assets/HelveticaNeueLTCom-BdCn.woff") format("woff"),
               url("${grailsApplication.config.grails.serverURL}/assets/HelveticaNeueLTCom-BdCn.svg#HelveticaNeueLTCom-BdCn") format("svg");
       -fs-pdf-font-embed: embed;
       -fs-pdf-font-encoding: Identity-H;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

`@font-face { src:url(${grailsApplication.config.app.serverUrl}/arialuni.ttf) ; -fs-pdf-font-embed: embed; -fs-pdf-font-encoding: Identity-H; }`

This worked for me.

Comment: Please, can you extend your answer with more detailed explanation? This will be very useful for understanding. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Probably the problem is that you have your `url` value surrounded by `'` instead of `"`.

The difference between them is that, though in Groovy string literals can be made with both, only the ones surrounded by `"` create GString, which evaluates statements between `${}`

Comment: The single quotes are in the CSS, not groovy code so it doesn't matter whether they are single or double quotes

Comment: @Cookalino well, can you explain to me what technology exactly will render this`'${grailsApplication.config.grails.serverURL}`? CSS? Did you downvoted my answer?

Comment: In response to your comment... If the single / double quotes were _inside_ the curly braces then you would have a point but they are outside the curly braces and so are not part of the groovy code. The code is going to resolve to either `src: url('myServerUrl')` or `src: url("myServerUrl")` in the CSS. CSS doesn't care about whether they are single or double quotes. Unfortunately if your answer doesn't make sense then it will get downvoted so that the best answers rise to the top. Maybe you can delete your answer to avoid it getting downvoted?

Comment: @Cookalino the question was what and how will evaluate `${grailsApplication.config.grails.serverURL}`? Because I think this is [Groovy String interpolation](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/core-syntax.html#_string_interpolation)

Comment: It will evaluate to whatever is set in Config.groovy. For example if Config.groovy sets `grailsApplication.config.grails.serverURL` to `http://www.myserver.com` then the poster's code will evaluate to 
`src: url('http://www.myserver.com/fonts/HelveticaNeueLTCom-BdCn.ttf');`

Comment: @Cookalino and in the documentation link above, it states that it should be in `"` to be evaluated. Prove me wrong, if it's so, but you are still ignoring this info from Groovy documentation, to you it will somehow magically evaluate, and I'm quoting official doc. Where am I wrong, if you could point?

Comment: The file the poster is showing is showing is NOT a .groovy file, it is a GSP. Maybe that is the source of your confusion. If the item is not inside curly braces, it it not evaluated as groovy. I suggest you delete your answer to prevent further downvotes. Please don't reply again. I'm trying to be helpful but I've now explained the same thing 4 times, I don't have any more time to repeat it again.

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me

```
@font-face {
    src: url("path/to/KF-Kiran.ttf");
    -fs-pdf-font-embed: embed;
    -fs-pdf-font-encoding: cp1250;
}

div {
    font-family: 'KF-Kiran';  // here give the same name of .ttf file.
}
```